# Java code using Xerces's getElementsByTagName does not return child node

Tags: java, xml, xerces

I'm using Xerces parser in trying to parse the following XML snippet. I can find the "location-info" element by when I use the findElementsByTagName method to find Circle, I am getting an empty NodeList back. Can someone please spot check and see what I am doing wrong?

```
<urn:locationResponse xmlns:urn="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:geopriv:held">
<presence entity="pres:www.telecomsys.com" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf"
          xmlns:gp="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:geopriv10" xmlns:dm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:data-model"
          xmlns:gs="http://www.opengis.net/pidflo/1.0" xmlns:ca="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:geopriv10:civicAddr"
          xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <tuple id="FIRST_LOCATION">
        <status>
            <gp:geopriv>
                <location-info xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:geopriv10">
                    <gs:Circle srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">
                        <gml:pos>00.000000 -00.00000</gml:pos>
                        <gs:radius uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9001">200</gs:radius>
                    </gs:Circle>
                    <gp:confidence>95</gp:confidence>
                </location-info>
                <gp:usage-rules>
                    <gp:retransmission-allowed>yes</gp:retransmission-allowed>
                </gp:usage-rules>
                <gp:method>Derived</gp:method>
            </gp:geopriv>
        </status>
        <timestamp>2001-01-00T00:00Z</timestamp>
    </tuple>
</presence>
```

Following is my code which attempts to get the "Circle" tag out of this XML

```
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(PIDFLOParser.class);
    private static final String LOCATION_INFO = "location-info";
    private static final String CIRCLE = "Circle";

    // Use of the Document BuilderFactory to create a DocumentBuilder class.
    DocumentBuilderFactory fact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = fact.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlDoc)));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    Node node = doc.getDocumentElement();

    String root = node.getNodeName();
    System.out.println("Root Node: " + root);

    NodeList listResponse = doc.getElementsByTagName(LOCATION_INFO);
    if (listResponse.getLength() == 0) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s doesn't exist in the Document.", LOCATION_INFO));
    }

    Node firstNode = listResponse.item(0);
    listResponse = ((Element) firstNode).getElementsByTagName(CIRCLE);
    if (listResponse.getLength() == 0) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s doesn't exist in the Document.", CIRCLE));
    }

    listResponse = ((Element) firstNode).getElementsByTagNameNS("gs", CIRCLE);
    if (listResponse.getLength() == 0) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s doesn't exist in the Document when searching with namespace.", CIRCLE));
    }
```

Output of this code is:

```
    Root Node: urn:locationResponse
Circle doesn't exist in the Document.
Circle doesn't exist in the Document when searching with namespace.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for help!

**Updated after guido's comment about full URI of namespace**

```
...
    private static final String NS_GS = "http://www.opengis.net/pidflo/1.0";
...
    listResponse = ((Element) firstNode).getElementsByTagNameNS(NS_GS, CIRCLE);
    if (listResponse.getLength() == 0) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s doesn't exist in the Document when searching with namespace.", CIRCLE));
    }
```

Output is still the same:

```
Root Node: urn:locationResponse
Circle doesn't exist in the Document.
Circle doesn't exist in the Document when searching with namespace.
```

Comment: where are you using `findElementByTagName()` in your code?

Comment: you need to specify the namespace URI in your getElementsByTagName call

Comment: Thanks Braj. I corrected the title

Comment: Thanks guido. The first method (getElementsByTagName) works without requiring a namespace when looking up location-info, however when trying to get Circle, neither variation works. My code sample and output shows that neither could find the element

Comment: @user3589431 you need to use the URI not the namespace literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `getElementsByTagNameNS` you should specify the URI for the namespace, not the prefix used in the xml, so:

```
getElementsByTagNameNS("gs", CIRCLE);
```

should be:

```
getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.opengis.net/pidflo/1.0", CIRCLE);
```

because `gs:Circle` element is defined under the namespace URI:

```
xmlns:gs="http://www.opengis.net/pidflo/1.0"
```

To make namespaces to work, you need to set the factory for it:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory fact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 fact.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Or alternatively, you can just use simply (without namespaces) the full qualified name:

```
 getElementsByTagName("gs:Circle");
```

Note: also note that your xml is invalid in your question because it is missing the closing root element `</urn:locationResponse>`

Comment: Okay...so I don't know how to put line break in comments here. @guido, I am updating the code in original code block, but with the change you  suggested, I still can't get it to work. Please see the updated code above.

Comment: Thank you @guido. Setting factory to be namespace aware (fact.setNamespaceAware(true)) worked. Also, I swear I tested using the tag name as "gs:Circle" but it didn't work. However, I tried that now and that also worked. So thanks!